# Discontinuity across the cut of a function with a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a}}$ factor

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, cauchy-principal-value

I Got this function:
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a}}\int_{-1}^1d\omega \frac{\sqrt{\omega^2-a}}{(x-\omega)}\phi(\omega)$$

$\phi$ is a well-behaved function and $a$ is a positive real number.

I want to calculate the discontinuity across
the cut:
$$G(x)=F(x-i\epsilon)-F(x+i\epsilon)$$

So:
$$F(x+ i\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+ i\epsilon)^2-a}}\int_{-1}^1d\omega \frac{\sqrt{\omega^2-a}}{(x-\omega+ i\epsilon)}\phi(\omega)
$$

I can use Plemelj formula:
$$\int_{-1}^1d\omega \frac{\sqrt{\omega^2-a}}{(x-\omega+ i\epsilon)}\phi(\omega)=\int_{-1}^1d\omega \phi(\omega)\sqrt{\omega^2-a}\left[\mathcal{P}\left(\frac{1}{x-\omega}\right) - i\pi\delta(x-\omega)\right]$$
but for the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+ i\epsilon)^2-a}}$ I'm not sure what to do.
Can I assure that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+ i\epsilon)^2-a}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a}} \ ?$$
If so, then:
$$F(x+ i\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a}}\int_{-1}^1d\omega \mathcal{P}\left(\frac{\phi(\omega)\sqrt{\omega^2-a}}{x-\omega}\right) -
i\pi\phi(x)$$

Claiming that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x- i\epsilon)^2-a}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a}}$$
we obtain

$$G(x)=2i\pi\phi(x)$$

Is my procedure incorrect?